# c++: explain this function declaration

Tags: c++, syntax, function-declaration

```
class PageNavigator {
 public:
  // Opens a URL with the given disposition.  The transition specifies how this
  // navigation should be recorded in the history system (for example, typed).
  virtual void OpenURL(const GURL& url, const GURL& referrer,
                       WindowOpenDisposition disposition,
                       PageTransition::Type transition) = 0;
};
```

I don't understand what is that **=0;** part...what are we trying to communicate?

Comment: I see no definition of a function. I see a *declaration* of a pure virtual function. Pure due to the =0; syntax. Classes with such functions are automatically *abstract* and cannot be instantiated. They can only be used as base classes. Instantiation requires you to override those functions in some derived class.

Comment: noted the change and edited the title...thanx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'= 0' means it's a **pure virtual method**. It must be overriden in inheriting class.

If a class has a pure virtual method it is considered **abstract**. Instances (objects) of abstract classes cannot be created. They are intended to be used as base classes only.

Curious detail: '= 0' doesn't mean method has no definition (no body). You can still provide method body, e.g.:

```
class A
{
 public:
  virtual void f() = 0;
  virtual ~A() {}
};

void A::f()
{
  std::cout << "This is A::f.\n";
}

class B : public A
{
 public:
  void f();
}

void B::f()
{
  A::f();
  std::cout << "And this is B::f.\n";
}
```

Comment: doesn't the keyword virtual already say that? Or do you mean its an empty function: equivalent to replacing `=0;` with `{  }`

Comment: No, the `=0;` means that there's explicitly no implementation defined. As a consequence you cannot instantiate this class. Instead, you need to derive a subclass and implement this method in the subclass then instantiate that.

Comment: ok so having `{ }` means you can instantiate that class and call the `OpenURL()` method?

Comment: @deostroll: virtual functions without `=0` need to have implementation and don't have to be overridden in derived classes. virtual fcuntions with `=0` don't have to (but can) have implementation and need to be overridden in derived classes.

Comment: You need to instantiate a subclass, because an abstract class can't be instantiated.

Comment: +1 for emphasizing that the derived class must override that function.

Comment: @sharptooth : Do you mean you can have a method with `=0` _with_ an implementation ? Or did I misunderstood ?

Comment: @kbok: Yes, you can in C++, but you still need to override such method in a derived class.

Comment: But what is the point then, if the implementation is deemed to be replaced ?

Comment: @kbok: You can have a default implementation that way.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [pure virtual function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#C.2B.2B_2) - there's no definition in the base class, making this an abstract class, and any instantiable class that inherits from PageNavigator must define this function.

Answer (score 0):

The  = 0 means the function is a pure virtual or abstract function, which in practice means two things:

a) A class with an abstract function is an abstract class. You cannot instantiate an abstract class.

b) You have to define a subclass which overrides it with an implementation.